# How do I extract just a single data element using usaddress?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm attempting to access one data element from `usaddress`. For example, `PlaceName` is the city field of the address. `usaddress` returns an ordered dictionary. I'm just trying to extract one value from the ordered dictionary.

```py
import usaddress

temp = usaddress.parse("ZENIA, CA 95595")

print(temp)

try:

    print(temp.get['PlaceName'])

except AttributeError:

    print("ERROR")
```

Results:

```
[('ZENIA,', 'PlaceName'), ('CA', 'StateName'), ('95595', 'ZipCode')]

ERROR
```

I wanted just `ZENIA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the data in a form of a list. I think you can create a simple function to extract the info as follows:

```
import re
data = [('ZENIA,', 'PlaceName'), ('CA', 'StateName'), ('95595', 'ZipCode')]

def get_place_name(data):
    flag = False
    for info in data:
        if 'PlaceName' in info:
            return re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", '', info[0])
    return flag
```

Result:

```
res = get_place_name(data)
# 'ZENIA'
```

Answer (score 0):

## in python 3

```
import usaddress

addr = "ZENIA, CA 95595"
parsed_addr = usaddress.tag(addr)

print(parsed_addr)

try:
    place_name = parsed_addr[0]['PlaceName']
    print(place_name)
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import usaddress

temp = dict(usaddress.tag('ZENIA, CA 95595')[0])
print(temp['PlaceName'])
```

Your output would be:

```
ZENIA
```

For printing everything, just try:

```
print(temp)
```

Output is:

```
{'PlaceName': 'ZENIA', 'StateName': 'CA', 'ZipCode': '95595'}
```